# Using OR in statements with arrays, (C)

Tags: arrays, c, conditional-statements

I've been trying to make a username and password interface and I was wondering if it was possible to have an or statement within `strcmp` and if I could also use all values of the array within 1 string, Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int u, p;
    char Iuser[50],Ipass[50];
    char user[3][50] = { "user1", "user2", "user3" };
    char pass[3][50] = { "pass1", "pass2", "pass3" };
    
    printf("\n Enter your username:");
    gets(Iuser);
    u = strcmp(user[0|1|2], Iuser);
    if (u == 0) {
        printf("\n Enter your password");
        scanf("%s", &Ipass);
    } else {
        printf("\n Invalid Username, Try Again !");
    }
}
```

Comment: `user[0|1|2]` *first* calculates `0|1|2`, *then* accesses the array. Result of bitwise OR-ing 0, 1 and 2 is 3, though, which already is out of bounds of your `user` array, thus undefined behaviour – for the rest see answers given so far.

Comment: C is a programming language. You can actually write functions that do whatever you want, if the standard functions do not do exactly what you need.

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't do like that in C.

I'm stealing Aconcagua's comment about what it actually does:

> `user[0|1|2]` *first* calculates `0|1|2`, then accesses the array. Result of bitwise OR-ing 0, 1 and 2 is 3, though, which already is out of bounds of your `user` array, thus undefined behaviour

So, instead of

```
u=strcmp(user[0|1|2],Iuser);
if(u==0) {
```

You should do:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool u = strcmp(user[0], Iuser) == 0 ||
         strcmp(user[1], Iuser) == 0 ||
         strcmp(user[2], Iuser) == 0;
if(u) {
```

If the array of users is long or the number of users is not known at compile-time:

```
bool u = false;
for(int i = 0; i < number_of_users; ++i) {
    if(strcmp(user[i], Iuser) == 0) {
        u = true;
        break;
    }
}
if(u) {
```

Note: Don't use bitwise `OR`, `|`, for these comparisons. Using the logical `OR`, `||`, enables [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) so that it stops testing as soon as one condition is `true`, just like the loop above which `break`s out as soon as one condition has been found `true`.

Comment: For completeness you might include what original version *actually* does – see my comment to question (making it obsolete...).

Comment: @Aconcagua I stole your comment and put it in the answer :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should do

```
u=strcmp(user[0],Iuser)!=0 && strcmp(user[1], Iuser)!=0 && strcmp(user[2],Iuser)!=0;

 if(u==0) {
       //User exists so ask password
```

because strcmp accepts only two strings to compare. If you do a OR as u said it would be something strange like bitwise operation inside char arrays, I doubt it would ever compile and we don't want to do that.

Have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

`strcmp` cannot be used this way: `user[0|1|2]` evaluates to `user[3]`, which accesses an element of the array beyond the end of the array: `strcmp()` will have undefined behavior when it reads from this place.

The C library does not have a generic function to locate a string in an array, so you should write:

```
u = strcmp(user[0], Iuser) && strcmp(user[1], Iuser) && strcmp(user[2], Iuser);
```

Which is quite verbose and specific.

Note that you should always ask for a password to avoid giving information about user names to an intruder, so the code should be modified as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char Iuser[50];
    char Ipass[50];
    char user[3][50] = { "user1", "user2", "user3" };
    char pass[3][50] = { "pass1", "pass2", "pass3" };
    int nusers = sizeof(user) / sizeof(user[0]); // number of users
    int u;

    for (;;) {    
        printf("\n Enter your username:");
        if (scanf("%49s", Iuser) != 1)
            return 1;
        printf("\n Enter your password");
        if (scanf("%49s", Ipass) != 1)
            return 1;
        for (u = 0; u < nusers; u++) {
            if (strcmp(user[u], Iuser) == 0 && strcmp(pass[u], Ipass) == 0)
                break;
        }
        if (u < nusers)
            break;
        printf("\n Invalid Username and/or password, Try Again !");
    }
    // user has been authenticated.
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Note also that password should be read without echoing the characters to the terminal, which is tricky but can be achieved on unix systems via `getpass`:

```
 #include <pwd.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 char *getpass(const char *prompt);
```

Passwords should not be stored in clear text as you do, nor as encrypted text because they would be too easy to find. Computing a cryptographic hash is recommended, in addition to more advanced techniques.